# php session problems when opening multiple window tabs

Tags: php, session

I have a php page that starts with a session_start() and it stores the user info in the session variables.   After that it goes either into (1) the long loop script does calculations  or (2) data query part depending on the _POST data from the previous form submit.

I want to do some queries even when the script is still looping and fetching data in another window. So I would have 2 window tab with the same php page that does (1), (2) respectively.

The problem is this can't be done unless I use session_destroy() when I do (1) and before the loop script.  Otherwise (2) would be loading and can't be opened.   I really don't want to destroy the session otherwise the user would have to login again and again.  Is that possible?  Thanks.

p.s: When I do (1) and I open an incognito window to do (2).  I don't have this problem even without the session_destory().

the code looks like this:

```
<?php 

session_start();

echo "<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' id='one' name='one' value='one'>
<input type='submit' id='two' name='two' value='two'>
</form>";

$if_one = $_POST["one"];
$if_two = $_POST["two"];
if ($if_one) loop();
if ($if_two) query();

function loop()
{
    //session_destroy();
    $y = 0;

    for ($i=0; $i<20000000; $i++)
    {
         $y += ($i * $i) % 5;
    }
    echo $y;
}

function query()
{
    echo '222';
}

?>
```

Comment: I find it easier to follow the logical process if one posts code, considering code is more or less logic.

Comment: Why do you need to use `session_destroy`, exactly? Has the cookie/headers been sent before the long loop?  If not, the problem is that the session hasn't been started yet, in the sense that the browser has the session ID to bring to the new window.

Comment: I can query at the same (1) is looping is when I destroy the session.  I'll try to post a short code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just solved it.  Instead of using `session_destroy()`, `session_write_close()` would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do that,

when u call session_start(); a session is created and it is active until the timeout in php.ini or you call session_destroy();

your error is somewhere else, do you call session_start after echo or print?

Comment: session_start() is the first line of my php file.@@

Comment: @Chandler - Does the "long loop" start before or after echoing or printing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem isn't with the session in multiple windows, but with the first script running the long loop before outputting any headers, specifically the session ID cookie that other pages would need to use the same session.  You should probably start the session and store your variables and then either redirect the user to another page for the long loop or output some kind of content, such as "Welcome! Starting Long Loop..."

Comment: I am trying to keep it in the same page for now.  But that seems doable and I'll try that if my problem cannot be solved.